# Multiple vertical shaded area

Tags: r, area

I am plotting the proportion of deep sleep (y axis) vs days (x axis). I would like to add vertical shaded area for a better understanding (e.g. grey for week-ends, orange for sick period...).

I have tried using geom_ribbon (I created a variable taking the value of 30, with is the top of my y axis if the data is during the WE - information given in another column), but instead of getting rectangles, I get trapezes.

In another post, someone proposed the use of "geom_rect", or "annotate" if one's know the x and y coordinates, but I don't see how to adapt it in my case, when I want to have the colored area repeated to all week-end (it is not exactly every 7 days because some data are missing).

Do you have any idea ?
Many thanks in advance !

```
  ggplot(Sleep.data, aes(x = DATEID)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = P.DEEP, group = 1), col = "deepskyblue3") + 
  geom_point(aes(y = P.DEEP, group = 1, col = Sign.deep)) +
  guides(col=FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max.WE), fill = '#6495ED80') +
  facet_grid(MONTH~.) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 15, col = "forestgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 20, col = "forestgreen", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(7,14,21,28), col = "grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,28,7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,30,5)) +
  labs(x = "Days",y="Proportion of deep sleep stage", title = "Deep sleep")
```

[Proportion of deep sleep vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Rbe.jpg)

[Head(Sleep.data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W29Jp.jpg)

```
> dput(head(Sleep.data))
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 16L), .Label = c("01-Dec-17", 
"01-Feb-18", "01-Jan-18", "02-Dec-17", "02-Feb-18", "02-Jan-18", 
"03-Dec-17", "03-Feb-18", "03-Jan-18", "04-Dec-17", "04-Feb-18", 
"04-Jan-18", "05-Dec-17", "05-Feb-18", "05-Jan-18", "06-Dec-17", 
"06-Feb-18", "06-Jan-18", "07-Dec-17", "07-Feb-18", "07-Jan-18", 
"08-Dec-17", "08-Jan-18", "09-Dec-17", "09-Feb-18", "09-Jan-18", 
"10-Dec-17", "10-Jan-18", "11-Dec-17", "11-Feb-18", "11-Jan-18", 
"12-Dec-17", "12-Jan-18", "13-Dec-17", "13-Feb-18", "13-Jan-18", 
"14-Dec-17", "14-Feb-18", "14-Jan-18", "15-Dec-17", "15-Jan-18", 
"16-Dec-17", "16-Jan-18", "17-Dec-17", "17-Jan-18", "18-Dec-17", 
"18-Jan-18", "19-Dec-17", "19-Jan-18", "20-Dec-17", "21-Dec-17", 
"21-Jan-18", "22-Dec-17", "22-Jan-18", "23-Dec-17", "23-Jan-18", 
"24-Dec-17", "24-Jan-18", "25-Dec-17", "25-Jan-18", "26-Dec-17", 
"26-Jan-18", "27-Dec-17", "27-Jan-18", "28-Dec-17", "28-Jan-18", 
"29-Dec-17", "29-Jan-18", "30-Dec-17", "30-Jan-18", "31-Dec-17", 
"31-Jan-18"), class = "factor"), DATEID = 1:6, MONTH = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Decembre", "Janvier", "Février"
), class = "factor"), DURATION = c(8.08, 7.43, 6.85, 6.23, 7.27, 
6.62), D.DEEP = c(1.67, 1.37, 1.62, 1.75, 1.95, 0.9), P.DEEP = c(17L, 
17L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 12L), STIMS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 390L, 147L
), D.REM = c(1.7, 0.95, 0.95, 1.43, 1.47, 0.72), P.REM = c(17L, 
11L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 9L), D.LIGHT = c(4.7, 5.12, 4.27, 3.05, 3.83, 
4.98), P.LIGHT = c(49L, 63L, 55L, 43L, 49L, 66L), D.AWAKE = c(1.45, 
0.58, 0.47, 0.87, 0.37, 0.85), P.AWAKE = c(15L, 7L, 6L, 12L, 
4L, 11L), WAKE.UP = c(-2L, 0L, 2L, -1L, 3L, 1L), AGITATION = c(-1L, 
-3L, -1L, -2L, 2L, -1L), FRAGMENTATION = c(1L, -2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
-1L), PERIOD = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("HOLIDAYS", 
"SICK", "WE", "WORK"), class = "factor"), SPORT = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Day", "Evening"), class = "factor"), 
    ACTIVITY = structure(c(6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Bkool", "eBike", "Gym", "Natation", "Run"), class = "factor"), 
    TABLETS = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), Ratio = c(1.15, 
    2.36, 3.45, 2.01, 5.27, 1.06), Sign = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Sign.ratio = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), Sign.deep = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Sign.awake = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), Sign.light = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    index = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), min = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), max.WE = c(30, 
    30, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DATE", "DATEID", "MONTH", "DURATION", 
"D.DEEP", "P.DEEP", "STIMS", "D.REM", "P.REM", "D.LIGHT", "P.LIGHT", 
"D.AWAKE", "P.AWAKE", "WAKE.UP", "AGITATION", "FRAGMENTATION", 
"PERIOD", "SPORT", "ACTIVITY", "TABLETS", "Ratio", "Sign", "Sign.ratio", 
"Sign.deep", "Sign.awake", "Sign.light", "index", "min", "max.WE"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `geom_ribbon` will give you trapezoids because it's growing from zero to 30 each time you encounter a weekend date. I think `geom_rect` will be a better solution, especially if you can figure out a way to make a 2nd data frame that holds the beginning and ending of each weekend. Hard to give more specific advice without a sample of what `Sleep.data` looks like, e.g. by including the output of `dput(head(Sleep.data))`.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you for your reply. Indeed, this is what I got, but so far I don't see how to format the data to be able to use geom_rect. Also, I would like to add more vertical shaded areas afterwards, e.g. the periods of sickness (recorded so far in column "PERIOD" as well. I added the output of head(sleep.data) and dput(head(Sleep.data)) in the post as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for adding the data, that makes it easier to understand exactly what you're working with and to confirm that an answer actually addresses your question.

I thought it would be helpful to make a separate table with just the start and end of each contiguous set of rows with the same `PERIOD`. I did this using `dplyr::case_when`, assuming we should mark dates as a "start" if they are the first row in the table (row_number() == 1), or they have a different PERIOD value than the prior row. I mark dates as an "end" if they are the last row of the table, or have a different PERIOD than the next row. I only keep the starts and ends, and spread these into new columns called `start` and `end`.

```
library(tidyverse)    
Period_ranges <- Sleep.data %>%
  mutate(period_status = case_when(row_number() == 1      ~ "start",
                               PERIOD != lag(PERIOD)  ~ "start",
                               row_number() == n()    ~ "end",
                               PERIOD != lead(PERIOD) ~ "end",
                               TRUE ~ "other")) %>%
filter(period_status %in% c("start", "end")) %>%
select(DATEID, PERIOD, period_status) %>%
mutate(PERIOD_NUM = cumsum(PERIOD != lag(PERIOD) | row_number() == 1)) %>%
spread(period_status, DATEID)

# Output based on sample data only. If there's a problem with the full data, please add more. To share full data, use `dput(Sleep.data)` or to share 20 rows use `dput(head(Sleep.data, 20))`.
>Period_ranges
   PERIOD PERIOD_NUM end start
 1     WE          1   2     1
 2   WORK          2   6     3
```

We can now use that in the plot. If you want to toggle the inclusion or fiddle with the appearance separately of different PERIOD types, you could modify the code below with `Period_ranges %>% filter(PERIOD == "WE"),`

```
ggplot(Sleep.data, aes(x = DATEID)) +

  # Here I specify that this geom should use its own data.
  # I start the rectangles half a day before and end half a day after to fill the space.
  geom_rect(data = Period_ranges, inherit.aes = F,
            aes(xmin = start - 0.5, xmax = end + 0.5,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 30,
                fill = PERIOD), alpha = 0.5) +
  # Here we can specify the shading color for each type of PERIOD
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "WE" = '#6495ED80',
    "WORK" = "gray60"
  )) +
  # rest of your code
```

Chart based on data sample:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great and very detailed answer. It works perfectly, and in addition I learnt a useful dplyr functions (case_when). I only need to update to have the data from the various months not mixed together, so far it is nearly working, expect that I get some unexpected NA values. I only added the column "MONTH" in the selection (select(DATEID, MONTH, PERIOD, period_status))